# PHP binding paramenters with default values

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm trying to convert this sql query to a prepared statement:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO contact VALUES (default,'".$firstName."', '".$lastName."');";
```

Where default is an id that is auto incremented.

Here's what my current prepared statement:

```
if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO contact (id, firstName, lastName) VALUES (DEFAULT, ?, ?)"))) {
            echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
        }
        if (!$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['firstName'], $_POST['lastName'])) {
            echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
        }
        if (!$stmt->execute()) {
            echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
        }
```

When I went to my PHP form, there none of the echo statements where executed, so I'm assuming that there were "no" errors. But when I checked my database, there were no new inserts; the insert method did not work. Nothing was added. I was wondering if there is a error in my bind_param function?

Comment: You mean that you specify the data types to bind as `"s"` and then bind 2 values.  Perhaps `"ss"`?

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Specify the data types to bind as "s" and then bind 2 values. I changed "s" to "ss". Thanks to Nigel Ren for the answer.